# two jars with some functions but with different version number

Tags: java, jar

My Application has two jars with some functions but with different version number.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody nobody  87776 Jul 16 23:40 commons-io-1.3.2.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody nobody 109043 Jul 16 23:35 commons-io-1.4.jar
```

One jar 1.4.jar has method deleteQuietly(),  but lower version 1.3.1 jar has no.

My puzzle is if report the error when I call the method?

cannot find symbol
symbol  : method deleteQuietly(java.io.File)

I encounter this error when I had this case:

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking, but the best advice would simply be to NOT do that.  Use only one version of the JAR at compile / build time, and the same version (only) at run time.

If you have two versions of a JAR with APIs that are not 100% compatible (in both directions) then the behaviour will depend on which JAR file comes first on the classpath.  If the version without the method comes first, you will either get build errors (like the one in your error message) or runtime errors.

---

I'm a little puzzled that you think it could possibly work.  Perhaps you think that Java will load both versions of the class and use some sort of magic to pick methods from the different versions.  It doesn't work like that.  Java will load the first version of the class that it encounters: any others will be silently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This is classloader issue. Remove commons-io-1.3.2.jar from your classpath and redeploy again.If you do not want to remove this jar, use maven to avoid class loading issue.

Comment: Maven use one jar that declare on dependency tag.It solve jar duplication as like as jiafu's question.